# 8 is not less than or equal to 30?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

Alright, I've got a `RangeValidator`:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="DateRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateRange"
    ErrorMessage="The date range must be at least 1 day, not more than 30, and neither date can be greater than today's date."
    EnableClientScript="true" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="30" CssClass="errortext span9 offset2"
    Display="Dynamic" />
```

And as you can see the minimum is 1 and the maximum is 30.

---

That is validating a hidden field **(it's visible at the moment cause I'm testing)**:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="DateRange" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And as you can see I've set the client ID to be static so it's finding the control just fine.

---

That hidden field is populated by this JavaScript method when one of the two dates change:

```
$('.datepicker').change(function () {
    var startDate = new Date($('#StartDate').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#EndDate').val());

    if (startDate > Date() || endDate > Date()) {
        $('#DateRange').val(-1);
    }
    else {
        var nDifference = endDate - startDate;
        var one_day = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
        $('#DateRange').val(Math.round(nDifference / one_day) + 1);
    }

    Page_ClientValidate(null);
});
```

And this method is working perfectly from the perspective of setting the correct number of days difference.

---

When the `Page_ClientValidate` is called I've debugged it to ensure the validator is firing as expected, and it is, and it has the values I would expect.  When the minimum is checked it's grabbing 1 ... and when that is compared to a value of 8 ... it's evaluating as expected ... 8 is greater than or equal to 1.

However, when the maximum is checked, even though it's grabbing 30 for the maximum ... when it's compared to a value of 8 ... the expression that says 8 is less than or equal to 30 is being evaluated to false.

---

I really hope somebody can help me out here!

**How in the world is 8 not less than 30 here?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing a [`Type="Integer"`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx) on your `RangeValidator`.

Comment: Very good answer, thank you! And @T.J.Crowder, you're an example of what this community should be like. Further, next time I will be sure to clearly identify that the work is being done on one side or the other.

Comment: @BigM: Gosh, that's very kind. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Add `Type="Integer"` to your range validator

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the type on the `RangeValidator`:

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="DateRangeValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DateRange"
    ErrorMessage="The date range must be at least 1 day, not more than 30, and neither date can be greater than today's date."
    EnableClientScript="true" MinimumValue="1" MaximumValue="30" CssClass="errortext span9 offset2"
    Display="Dynamic"
    Type="Integer" />
```

Relevant MSDN docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type.aspx